# How can I modify this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm using the Google Local Search API and Google Maps API.  See here: http://geodit.com:8000/test

You can perform a search, and then the javascript fills the Map, as well as the results next to the map.

I think this function fills the results next to the map:

```
function OnLocalSearch()
```

My question is: how can I change the results displayed? Right now, by default it shows the Name of the business and the address. How can I disable the business link? And then add more text to each search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to hide .gs-title if you want to eliminate the business name altogether.  If you want to disable the links, style a.gs-title to look normal, and capture/disable clicks on that selector using jQuery or whatever.

Comment: How do I add a button to the bottom of it?